# HTTP2 multi request/response over single tcp connection

Tags: tcp, http2, multiplexing

just want to know that how could or where we can check multiple request/response over single tcp connection in http2....i mean practically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome Developer Tools in the Network tab you can add the Connection ID column and if this is the same, then it's using the same connection:

[image: Connection ID column in Chrome Dev Tools]

Alternatively if you run the site through [WebPagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/) there is a handy Connection View.

Here you can see Amazon only uses two connections for images-na.ssl.com:

[image: Amazon Connection view from WebPagetest]

Rather than the usual 6 connections per domain when forcing HTTP/1.1:

[image: WebPagetest showing multiple connections under HTTP/1.1]

And the reason it uses two connections (and why you get 12 connections under HTTP/1.1 for some domains) is that anonymous CORS requests (that Amazon uses to download JavaScript by XHR) effectively count as a separate domain and so go under a separate connection in HTTP/2 and up to 6 more connections in HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Nice explanation.